# Search-Index: Best-Practises for formatting Index-Drive

Tags: search, index

I recently discovered [SRx-Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2016/02/01/announcing-the-search-health-reports-srx-for-sharepoint-search-diagnostics/) - a PowerShell-Toolset to troubleshoot SharePoint-Server Search.

The test [`OSVolumeProperties`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2016/03/25/search-health-reports-srx-summary-for-each-test/) recommends a NTFS-Blocksize of 64 Kilobytes for index data volumes:

```
OSVolumeProperties       Warning Index data volumes have configuration settings which do not follow recommended guidance
                         The following may cause performance issues:The following may cause performance issues:
                          * The index data volume I: on server XXX has a block size of 4096
                           - Formatting this volume with a 64KB block size is recommended for better performance
```

I was not able to find any documentation to that recommendation. Would be great if someone could provide some background.

Answer (score 2):

My non-technical explanation: The index consumes a huge amount of disk space. Generally grabbing more space than it needs so that it can later shrink the contents in a merge operation. This write optimization benefits from bigger chunks of disk blocks because there is less latency cause by seeking data that is scattered in smaller chunks.